# Number of cycles in ultrasound pulse

Tags: medical-physics

Why in clinical ultrasound is there 2-4 cycles per pulse?

I cant seem to find a reason why, this is happening

Has it to do with the piezoelectric not being instantaneously stopped when an electrical pulse is being applied?

Comment: Would you expect more or less cycles? And also what do you mean by "Has it to do with the piezoelectric not being instantaneously stopped when an electrical pulse is being applied?"?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by more or less cycles. With ref to my hack answer. I mean that when the electrical pluse hit the piezoelectrical a pluse is produced but in an ideal world I would want 1 cycle per pulse but the crytal goes through 2-4 cycles, when a pulse is produced. I say 2-4 because everywhere I looked even on echopedia it quotes this but with out a reason why.

Comment: The piezo (PZT) acts like a damped crystal oscillator.  When it is pulsed it 'rings' for a few cycles--its like a bell. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224183294_Low-Cost_Wideband_Ultrasonic_Transmitter_and_Receiver_for_Array_Signal_Processing_Applications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Has it to do with the piezoelectric not being instantaneously stopped
>   when an electrical pulse is being applied?

Your assumption is correct: a piezoelectric crystal will ring even if a single electrical pulse has been applied to it. The number of cycles depends on the damping characteristics of the transducer: the greater the damping, the fewer the number of cycles.

Without damping, a crystal could ring for a long time, but that may not be desirable in diagnostics, since the transducer is typically used to receive the reflected signal and, therefore it has to stop ringing before the reflected signal returns.

The diagram below, copied from [this site](http://echocardiographer.org/Echo%20Physics/BasicTransducers.html), shows basic elements of a transducer. The backing material behind the crystal is used to control damping.

[image]